# Construct a search string from three select elements?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to construct a search form and make a search on wordpress getting the values from two select elements from within the form. Anyone know how? Do I have to use JS, AJAX or both? Any help would be appreciated.

```
function categories_header_form()
{
?>
  <div id="header-form">
    <h3 class="form-title">
        <?php echo 'Αναζήτηση προϊόντων ανά περιοχή' ?>
    </h3>
    <form id="search-form" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get" >
      <div class="form-container">

        <?php nomoi(); ?>

        <?php products_selection(); ?>

        <button type="submit" class="button" id="search-form-button">Εύρεση</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<?php
}

function products_selection()
{
    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'seller',
      'taxonomy'    => 'category',
      'hide_empty'  => 0,
      'exclude'     => 1,1078,1079
    );
    $products = get_categories( $args );

    if ( $products ) {
    echo '<select id="products-select">';
      echo '<option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Προϊόντα</span></option>';

      foreach ($products as $product) {
        echo '<option class="product-name" id="'. $product->term_id .'">'. $product->name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
  }
}

function nomoi()
{
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'seller',
    'taxonomy'  => 'nomos',
    'hide_empty'=> 0,
    'parent'    => 0
  );

  $categories = get_categories( $args );

  if ( $categories ) {
    echo '<select id="nomoi-select" name="nomoi">';
      echo '<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"><span>Νομοί</span></option>';

      foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $id = $category->term_id;
        $name = $category->name;
        echo '<option class="nomos" id="'. $id .'">'. $name .'</option>';
      }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<select id="town-select" name="towns">';
      echo '<option class="town-disabled" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"><span>Πόλεις</span></option>';
    echo '</select>';
  }
}
```

This is my search form along with the select tags. I'm a starter in JS and AJAX and don't know how to perform the query correctly. The second select field is populated through AJAX

Comment: I haven't been able to construct the query yet. Working on it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to get the values from two select elements from within the form?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you could do it. Listen for changes to the select elements and save the value. Then use the values in the for the search query.

```js
(function(doc, undefined) {

  /** these 2 var must be available to the whole function */
  var el1, el2;

  var getSelectedValue = function(el) {
    /**
     * @params {object} el - HTML Element
     * @returns {string}
     */
    return el.selectedOptions[0].value;
  };

  var getSearchString = function(select1, select2) {
    /**
     * @params {object} el1 - HTML Element
     * @params {object} el2 - HTML Element
     * @returns {string}
     */
    return [getSelectedValue(select1), getSelectedValue(select2)].join(' ');
  };

  function delegator(event) {
    /**
     * @params {object} - Event Object
     * When change event occurs, evaluate the definition of el1 and el2.
     * Assign value to el1 if assigned already.
     * If el1 is assigned, check value of el2 and assign.
     * If both have valid assignments to the objects we need, then we can get the search string.
     */
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'change':
        if (el1 === undefined && el2 === undefined) {
          el1 = event.target;
        } else if (el1 instanceof HTMLSelectElement && el2 === undefined) {
          el2 = event.target;
        }
        if (el1 instanceof HTMLSelectElement && el2 instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
          doc.getElementById('search').setAttribute('value', getSearchString(el1, el2));
        }
        break;
    }

  }
  doc.addEventListener('change', delegator, false);
}(document, undefined));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Get Search String</title>
</head>

<body>


  <form id="my-select-form" name="my-select-form">
    <select id="products-select">
      <option selected="" disabled="" value="0"><span>Προϊόντα</span>
      </option>
      <option class="product-name" id="product_term_id">product_name</option>
    </select>

    <select id="nomoi-select" name="nomoi">
      <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled"><span>Νομοί</span>
      </option>
      <option class="nomos" id="id">name</option>
    </select>

    <select id="town-select" name="towns">
      <option class="town-disabled" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"><span>Πόλεις</span>
      </option>
      <option>Two</option>
      <option>Three</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <form id="my-search-form">
    <input id="search" type="search" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry  colecmc. Three select elements. I'll give it a go and let you know!! Thank you for your time!!

Comment: You should be able to extend the logic, just follow the pattern, declare a var and look for an undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help colecmc!